# How can I show only some columns using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, columnsorting

I have tried the following code and it works however it shows excess columns that I don't require. This is the output showing the extra columns: [image]

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.groupby(['City1', 'City2']).sum('PassengerTrips')
df['Vacancy'] = 1-df['PassengerTrips'] / df['Seats']
df = df.groupby(['City1','City2']).max('Vacancy')
df = df.sort_values('Vacancy', ascending =False)
print('The 10 routes with the highest proportion of vacant seats:')
print(df[:11])
```

I have tried to add the following code in after sorting the vacancy values however it gives me an error:

```
df = df[['City1', 'City2', 'Vacancy']]
```

Comment: Just do `df = df['Vacancy']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`City1` and `City2` are in index since you applied a `groupby` on it.
You can put those in columns using `reset_index` to get the expected result :

```py
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
df = df[['City1', 'City2', 'Vacancy']]
```

Or, if you want to let `City1` and `City2` in index, you can do as @Corralien said in his comment : `df = df['Vacancy']`

And even `df = df['Vacancy'].to_frame()` to get a `DataFrame` instead of a `Serie`.

Comment: Thanks @tlentali. If I were to use the df = df['Vacancy'] after the sort it gives the correct answer I'm looking for but does not show the column heading. Can this be resolved? Otherwise your version works but shows the index

Comment: You can try `df = df['Vacancy'].to_frame()`, I updated the answer to add that.